# Windows Hypervisor Platform is missing

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-emulator

I want to create a xamarin app, but i can't enable Windows Hypervisor Platform, because it is not listed. How should I enable it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Right-click on the windows logo and check the version of Windows you are using under the System option. You have to have at least Windows 10 Pro to enable Hyper-v. For a list of other requirements take a look at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v)

Comment: I have windows 10 enterprise

Comment: If that's the case I wonder if the option has been somehow been disabled through like network security or something. I'd follow that doc link and try enabling it with PowerShell if you haven't already. Also, if that doesn't work and if you have an intel cpu you could try using HAXM instead.

Comment: Microsoft: On Windows 10 October 2018 Update (RS5) and higher, you only need to enable Hyper-V, as it will use Windows Hypervisor Platform (WHPX) automatically. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?tabs=vswin&pivots=windows#hyper-v-win)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uncheck `Hyper-V`.

Then in Visual Studio go to Tools-Android-Android SDK Manager-Tools-Extras-Intel X86 ... and install this.

Start cmd and run:

```
dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V-All
```

Then reboot